# C# - LINQ - Sorting collection by double-nested properties

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Let's assume that we have a few classes:

```
public class SecondNestingLevel 
{
    public string SortPropety {get; set;}
}

public class FirstNestingLevel 
{
    public ICollection<SecondNestingLevel> SecondNestingLevelCollection {get; set;}
}

public class Wrapper 
{
    public ICollection<FirstNestingLevel> FirstNestingLevelCollection {get; set;}
}
```

I have to sort collection of `Wrapper` objects by `SortPropety` (located inside double-nested `SecondNestingLevel` objects).

Guidelines:

1. Firstly, aggregate together `Wrapper` objects, which every value of `SortPropety` is the same (in every `FirstNestingLevel` and `SecondNestingLevel` located inside specific `Wrapper` object).
2. Secondly, sort aggregated in this way `Wrapper` objects in a alphabetic way.

General schema of result collection:

- Part 1: Wrappers with the same value of `SortProperty` sorted in an alphabetic way.
- Part 2: Other wrappers sorted in an alphabetic way of `SortProperty` located in first `SecondNestingLevel` object which is placed in first `FirstNestingLevel` object in nested collections.

I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: What should happen for the wrapper objects which do not have the same value for all nested occurrences of SortProperty?

Comment: They should be placed after their equivalents with the same values of `SortProperty`.

Answer (score 1):

To order SortProperty I made this example:

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper()
{
    FirstNestingLevelCollection = new List<FirstNestingLevel>()
    {
        new FirstNestingLevel() { SecondNestingLevelCollection = new List<SecondNestingLevel>()
            { 
                new SecondNestingLevel() { SortPropety = "11" },
                new SecondNestingLevel() { SortPropety = "02" },
                new SecondNestingLevel() { SortPropety = "05" }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now to order SortPropety you need to go through each element in firstNestingLevel to be able to order SecondNestingLevel.

```
foreach (var firstNestingLevel in wrapper.FirstNestingLevelCollection)
{
    var orderedEnumerable = firstNestingLevel
        .SecondNestingLevelCollection.OrderBy(e => e.SortPropety);

    foreach (var secondNestingLevel in orderedEnumerable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(secondNestingLevel.SortPropety);
    }
}
```

If you need it in Linq, one way to go is using Select and you will get a nested loop of ordered elements:

```
var orderedEnumerable = wrapper.FirstNestingLevelCollection
    .Select(e => e.SecondNestingLevelCollection.OrderBy(e1 => e1.SortPropety));
```

To print that you can do something like:

```
foreach (var secondNestingLevels in orderedEnumerable)
{
    foreach (var secondNestingLevel in secondNestingLevels)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(secondNestingLevel.SortPropety);
    }
}
```

Both codes will give the same output:

```
02
05
11
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, it is really helpful but unfortunately, I have to do it by using LINQ :(, foreach is not allowed.

Comment: I have updated my answer with LINQ solution as well.